# Lubuntu installation failed. (I'm a noob)

Tags: system-installation, lubuntu

So I was trying to install lubuntu and it just failed.
Integrity test failed

The .pool/universe/live/libwnck/libwnck22_2.30.7-5.1ubuntu1_amd64.deb file failed the MD5 checksum verification. Your CD-ROM or this file may have been corrupted.

Does this mean my USB is damaged?
I'm sorry I'm so new to this.

Comment: You didn't say which release of Lubuntu, but the I'd recommend using the "*Check disk for defects*" option before install (ie. verify your install media is perfect).  Also Lubuntu documentation is found at https://manual.lubuntu.me/stable/1/Installing_lubuntu.html
Chapter 1.1 Retrieving the image - https://manual.lubuntu.me/stable/1/1.1/retrieving_the_image.html
Chapter 1.2 Booting the Image - https://manual.lubuntu.me/stable/1/1.2/booting_the_image.html
Chapter 1.3 Installation - https://manual.lubuntu.me/stable/1/1.3/installation.html  (*Check disk for defects* is mentioned in 1.3*)

Answer (score 3):

It means your .iso file was corrupted or incomplete. Download it again.